# equilibrium point of two unions

Tags: calculus

I am not a mathematician, so please bear with me. I am looking for a formula, where I could find an equilibrium point of two unions.

Union A = (10,8,7)
Union B = (5,6)

Could anyone be so nice and present me a formula on how to calculate this? A brief guide would be more than welcome.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Let's imagine this is demand and supply unions. Union A is demand Union B is supply. Hwo could I model the equilibrium point?

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Don't forget: you're not a mathematician, but we're no economists either. It is, to me at least, unclear what you mean by those terms.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I am not economist either, I just find it interesting to think about this problem. My idea is: if you have two forces, groups, unions and they interact with each other, they must have some equilibrium point... I really don't know how to describe this.

Comment: You could take the average of each group, and _then_ take the average of those two averages; that's how I am currently interpreting your question.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Yes, I have think of that too. But it seemed to easy:) Thank you.